# Wordpress toolset css struggle

Tags: css

I am struggeling to vertically align an image with a title text. Could someone please help? Link of page for debugging; http://www.batch7.no/produkt/firestone-rock/

[image: example]

Comment: You should ask this on stack overflow. It's not specifically WordPress related.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Chess Byte - this is a general web development question.

I suggest adding 30px padding to the top of the text : padding: 30px 0 15px 0;

Use developer tools (f12) and examine the object

- then add the above css or what ever you'd like. Good luck